# How do I use Python PIL to save an image to a particular directory?

Tags: python, image, directory, save

For example I want to manipulate some image and then save it to a particular directory. How do I save to a specific directory other than the one I am in?
I understand that this will save to the directory I am in:

```
from PIL import Image
""" Some Code """
img.save("sample.png", "")
```

How do I save to a different directory?

Comment: you use a complete path to the savefile, rather than a relative path - C:/somefolder/yourfilehere.jpg rather than just yourfilehere.jpg

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this

```
img.save('/absolute/path/to/myphoto.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Not OP but thanks for the answer. I'm a little confounded as to what the object `img` is. OP imported `Image` but didn't seem to use it or just didn't reveal it. What objects can call the `.save()` function?

Comment: @Bowen Liu `img` seems to be an instance of the `Image` class, which has the `.save()` function. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Comment: Your solution is saving it to .jpg format (which is not what is intended from the question).

Answer (score 13):

First create the directory before saving the image to the directory

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image_path = "path/to/image"

os.mkdir(image_path)
image = image.save(f"{image_path}/image.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code for saving image to a specific folder**

```
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
import os
url="https://bimber.bringthepixel.com/main/wp-content/uploads/sites/17/2018/07/neon_type2_v02.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join('E:/new projects of python/picture download','1.jpg'))
```