# Where are images saved when creating images with Pillow in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In these lines of code, I create a small red image and save it as "new_image.png". But I can't find the saved image, where is it saved? And can I change the place where I want to save my image?

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'red')
img.save("new_image.PNG")
```

Comment: Check out the directory of the python file, use this about how to save in a new path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434278/how-do-i-use-python-pil-to-save-an-image-to-a-particular-directory/31434485

Comment: Thank you! It works now!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Python PIL to save an image to a particular directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434278/how-do-i-use-python-pil-to-save-an-image-to-a-particular-directory)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'red')
img.save("new_image.PNG")
```

It works well for me:
[image]

The reason may because your current work path is not as you thought.
See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66449241/12838403

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a path, the image is saved in the same path as the python file generating the image

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'red')
img.save("new_image.PNG")
```

To save image in a directory you specify, you can use

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image_path = "path/to/image"
image = image.save(f"{image_path}/image.png")
```

**Note:** If this directory does not exist, you would have to create it before saving your image in it.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image_path = "path/to/image"

os.mkdir(image_path)
image = image.save(f"{image_path}/image.png")
```