# How would I search for files in Python in a similar way to JavaScript?

Tags: python

This is about file directories.
So in Javascript I understand how to work back from code files to find other files.
Something like:

`require('../folder/file')`

I am unsure of how to do something like this in Python.
I am currently trying to open a file using `.open()`, however I am getting an error message saying the file/directory can't be found, and will only work if I put this in the directory BEFORE the one in the code. So I would like to know how to open files using the paths as I have explained.

Answer (score 3):

First, check the current location of your program:

```
import os
 
print("current location-> %s" %os.getcwd())
```

From experience, you are actually not in the location you thought.

Then, set the current location by

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

**Here I post a complete version:**

```
import os
 
print("current location-> %s" %os.getcwd())
 
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
 
def read_file() :
    with open(current_path + "/user_info.txt" , encoding = 'utf-8') as f_obj :
        content = f_obj.readline()
        print("content -> %s" %content)
 
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    read_file()
```

Another way to do so is to open a file using the absolution path.
like

```
C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\a.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to open a file in an folder ontop of your current working folder i.E:

```
-Folder
--test.txt
-main.py
```

then you would use something like this

```
with open('./test/test.txt','r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

the `../` indicates you want to go one folder back.
to start from your current working folder, where you main.py lies, you use `./`

Comment: this is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/als0010/Documents/School/Software Development/School/fileHandling/fileOpen.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open('../random.txt','r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../random.txt'

Comment: You are probably not considering the working directory of your python program. That's the pain working with relative path. Guessing here, but it seems your current working directory is `/School` and not `/School/fileHandling`. You can check that by using `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 1):

to open a file in your current directory

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
```

And to specify a location

```
f = open("D:\\path_to_file\file.txt", "r")
```

I would also use a context manager so something like

```
with open("D:\\path_to_file\file.txt", "r") as file:
# Do task
```

this will handle closing the file/connection automatically