# How to save a file based on the department Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-imaging-library

I have this data below and I am generating certificate
Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Documents/AUTOMATED CERT TOOL/name.list.xlsx')
print(data)

im = Image.open('C:/Users/Documents/AUTOMATED CERT TOOL/cert_template.png')

name_list = data["Name"].tolist() 
serial_list = data["Serial"].tolist()
department_list = data["Department"].tolist()


for name in name_list:
    for serial in serial_list:
        
        im = Image.open("C:/Users/Documents/AUTOMATED CERT TOOL/cert_template.png")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=90)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = 800, 1150, 1600, 100
        w, h = draw.textsize(name, font=font)
        x = (x2 - x1 - w)/2 + x1
        y = (y2 - y1 - h)/2 + y1
        draw.text((x, y), name, align='center',fill='black', font=font)
        d1 = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        location1 = (2000,150)
        text_color1 = (0, 0, 0)
        font1 = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)
        d1.text(location1, serial, fill = text_color1, font = font1)
        

        im.save(name +".pdf")
```

I would like to save the certificate in each folder based on the department.
For example, if department is FTSM, certificate should be saved in the FTSM folder.

Can someone help me, please

Comment: Your file names contain 2 extensions? also you need double '//' for directories or encompass them in ' ' not  " ".

Comment: In the original Excel table does a Name correspond to a single specific Serial?

Comment: @MadisonCourto, yes one is the cert template and another one is the name list .

Comment: @pavel ,yes single specific serial for each name

Comment: Unrelated: I can't imagine the PNG certificate template will change between your loops, nor will the 2 fonts that you load. As such, they are *"loop invariant"* so you should consider loading them **outside** the loops to improve performance. Then just use `im = alreadyLoadedImage.copy()` inside the loop and work on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Documents/AUTOMATED CERT TOOL/name.list.xlsx')
print(data)

im = Image.open('C:/Users/Documents/AUTOMATED CERT TOOL/cert_template.png')

name_list = data["Name"].tolist() 
serial_list = data["Serial"].tolist()
department_list = data["Department"].tolist()


for name in name_list:
    # You could 'zip' both lists together, to iterate over them simultaneously
    for serial, department in zip(serial_list, department_list):
        
        im = Image.open("C:/Users/Documents/AUTOMATED CERT TOOL/cert_template.png")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=90)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = 800, 1150, 1600, 100
        w, h = draw.textsize(name, font=font)
        x = (x2 - x1 - w)/2 + x1
        y = (y2 - y1 - h)/2 + y1
        draw.text((x, y), name, align='center',fill='black', font=font)
        d1 = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        location1 = (2000,150)
        text_color1 = (0, 0, 0)
        font1 = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)
        d1.text(location1, serial, fill = text_color1, font = font1)
        
        # Set the path where you want to save the file - Adjust to match your file path needs
        fileSavePath = '/absolute/path/to/yourPhoto/' + department + '/' + name + '.pdf'

        im.save(fileSavePath, 'PDF')
```

The link below may help a bit as well:

[How do I use Python PIL to save an image to a particular directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434278/how-do-i-use-python-pil-to-save-an-image-to-a-particular-directory)

Comment: hi thank you for answering the question. I tried out but it seems to save the names in all folders. Not following according to the department. Ex:  I have 5 names all 5 names are in each department folder.

Comment: Thanks I found the solution : zipping the department and name together and bringing it out of the second for loop helped to solve the problem. 

I learn something new which is the zipping in for loop . thank you so much really appreciate it.